How can I make and armaebi-v7a apk on Unreal Engine 5.4.4?
I need to make an apk with Unreal Engine 5.4.4, already have the project finished, but can’t find how to make this apk compatible with armeabi-v7a devices, there’s only arm64 option in the android section on project settings. Is that impossible to make an armv7 apk on unreal engine 5.4.4? Please can anyone help me with that?

Based on: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/how-to-add-support-for-armabi-v7-architecture-in-my-unreal-engine-5-project/530902/2 and https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/ue5-android-32-bit-are-7-build/233850/5 it looks like Unreal 5.x dropped support for older armv7
